# Is the exponential map a global diffeomorphism when g is nilpotent?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have a question about the exponential aplication: if $\mathfrak{g}$ is a complex semisimple and nilpotent Lie algebra, is true that the exponential map is a global diffeomorphism?

Comment: By "application", you mean "map" or "function". Note that the exponential map is only defined when you choose a Lie group with that Lie algebra. Then the exponential map in the case you propose will be bijective if the group chosen is simply connected. (The complex torus serves as a simple counterexample otherwise)